# Prepend any text to URL without effect on URL?

Tags: javascript, url

is it possible to prepend any text to a URL that have no effect on that URL. I know, it sounds crazy but I want that URL will be opened in PDF viewer if somebody clicks on button (JavaScript, already done). This URL should be for example www.example.com. The Problem is that every URL that should be opened from PDF viewer is shown in Security Warning Popup as "are you sure that you want to open www.example.com ........". So what I want is that URL like googlesupportsearch.www.example.com will be shown in the Security Warning and not www.example.com. I know, every URL that is shown in security warning will be actually opened as shown! But I have tried to open an URL with any prepended text and I am sure it worked but today, I took the same URL and it does not work! 
 
Is there any possibility to prepare URL that looks different as it works? kdajfjhasdjkf.www.example.com -> opens www.example.com

Comment: Security measures are generally designed such that they cannot be circumvented. That's why they're called, "security measures".

Answer (score 1):

No.

If it was possible then it would be vulnerable to an attack along the lines of: `www.a-well-known-site-that-you-know-is-trustworthy.com.just.ignore.the.evil.malicious.hacking.site`.

You can't get a security warning to lie about the URL it is warning about.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I want to do, not to hack but to embellish the URL! Because I just want to log on my website who opened a PDF file that I created. www.a-well-known-site.com.just.www.my-website.com and to log on my-website.com that user with public IP address opened your PDF!